# How to create Angular Package using ng-packagr without the Cli?

Tags: angular

I want to run a command and create angular package with ng-packagr.

The problem I [can't find any documentation](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) about which command to run to do that except using Angular Cli. But I don't and can't do that with Angular Cli for some reasons.

I looking for a command to create a package structure with the files. something like:

```
ng-packagr create my-lib
```

the output should be like angular cli does `ng g library my-lib`

Comment: Hi, follow this article. https://medium.com/swlh/angular-library-with-ng-packagr-13f20ed202bd

Comment: I read this article, and it's not explain how to create without the cli.